# Grid: Generic filters Vs column level filters

Tags: user-behavior, navigation, accessibility, web

I had a case where there is a view and on that user can apply any filter.
Once filter is applied > it affects all the tabs present in that view.

Is this approach right.
Check this image 
[image]

Or should it be the reverse?
Where filter has to be applied to each tab separately 
check this image.

[image]

Comment: it depends from the use cases, but whatever solution you choose you have to make visually clear the scope of the filter

Comment: +1, impossible to say as your UI doesn't appear to have any data...

Comment: So you're saying that each tab has it's own filter? Because that's what that implies. Plus, in mobile a user has to go to each tab and filter what potentially will be the same in each tab? That's too much user effort...

Answer (score 1):

> Once filter is applied > it affects all the tabs present in that view

**Grid level filter**:
In your case the first option with having single generic filter makes more sense, because it affects all columns of that grid.

**Column level filter**:
The second approach comes into picture when you want to look for data into a particular column without affecting other columns of that grid.

If the business requires you to have the second option, go for it. In most cases the first option works best.

Comment: Can you share a wireframe

Answer (score 0):

Which of your two functionalities does the task of the human end user require? Rationalize that decision, unless it's arbitrary.

Do what the task demands first, and then make sure the system's cause-and-effect behavior is clearly conveyed to the user through proper labeling and status and info hierarchy. [Nielsen's heuristics checklist](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/) is hard to beat when you just need some sound theory to base a decision on before any testing with niche users.